# "Content-Type:text/plain" forces to download the file

Tags: php, google-chrome, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

If I call `header('Content-Type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15');` the browser will download the file instead of showing it. Using `text/html` works instead. (the downloaded file is processed anyway, it's not downloading the source code)

I've tried to add `header('Content-Disposition:inline;');` but it was just ignored.

I'm pretty clueless about what could cause this problem, any tip?

The server is MAMP 1.9.6 (PHP 5.3.5, Apache/2.0.64).

edit: this only happens on Chrome, it works on Firefox, Camino and Safari.

Comment: What browser is it? I'm pretty sure IE prompts a download when it encounters anything other than `image/*` and `text/html`. This is why javascript/css files are downloaded rather than displayed.

Comment: That's strange, never seen it (also can't reproduce) :(

Comment: @rudi_visser: you are on the right track: it works on Firefox, Camino and Safari. Looks like it's Chrome's fault. If anyone knows a workaround, I'll try, otherwise I'll just go back to text/html :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this with this script:

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15');
  echo "This is some text";
```

However, I can reproduce it with this:

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15');
  echo "\x00This is some text";
```

Make sure that your content actually *is* plain ASCII text...

Comment: That's it, I guess. I assumed the browser would have tried to display it anyway even if there were control characters. Looks like I assumed wrong.

Answer (score -4):

For me this works:

```
header('Content-Type:text/javascript;');
```