# How to show file in GWT client side, instead of Downloading:

Tags: gwt, browser

I need little help to achieve this, in my app user can upload files to server and its stored as blob object, and now i need to show them to user up on there request.

What I am up to is show in below code,

On server side I put content to response:
(This code is implemented based on this blog post [WaterTalks](http://de-water-talks.blogspot.in/2013/03/gwt-file-uploading-and-save-it-to-db.html))

```
     resp.setContentType("text/plain");
     resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.txt");

     PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
     out.println("This is the output content");
     out.println("Probably something dynamic should go in here:::::");


PersistenceManager pm = null;
         try {
                pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
                javax.jdo.Transaction transaction = pm.currentTransaction();
                Extent e = pm.getExtent(WaterTalkFiles.class, true);
                Iterator iter = e.iterator();
                String returns = "";
                WaterTalkFiles file  =  (WaterTalkFiles)iter.next();
                Blob blob = file.getData();
                byte[] buffer = blob.getBytes();
                String s = new String(buffer);
                out.println(s);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
                if (null != pm)
                      pm.close();
         }
```

Now in client side when user click show button i want to show the file content in browser, not to download it.

My client side code is:

```
showfilecontentButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                   String link = "/FileUploadByWaterTalks";
                    container.add(new HTML("<a href=\"" + link + "\">ShowFile</a>"));
            }
        });
```

The code above (Client side code) not showing content of file its just downloading the file.
But I don't want user to download it, I want show them the content of it.

And, do I have to configure something over here to work it out.

```
 resp.setContentType("text/plain");
 resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.txt");
```

Hope you got what my problem is. Please be free to share your thoughts and solutions to achieve this.

Thanks.

---

### **UPDATED**

Up on the bases of first answer here, I changed some portion of my code:

updated code sections are:

```
    resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");



final String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/FileUploadByWaterTalks";
String name = "output.txt";

Anchor link1 = new Anchor(name);
RootPanel.get().add(link1);
link1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Frame f = new Frame(url);
        f.setSize("600px", "400px");
        f.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(0, Unit.PX);
        RootPanel.get().add(f);
      }
    });
```

But still the browser asking me to save the file instead of showing it in the browser itself.

Comment: Any chance your content is not ascii - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877140/content-typetext-plain-forces-to-download-the-file

Comment: Huh..!!! so you are saying that I have to change my response.setHeader() arguments, will please prefer me some documents related to it, I am also Googling it :)

Comment: That or the content might have non-ascii stuff or browser dependent.

Comment: Ohh..!!! I am not getting you, what actually you are trying to say??!!
first you said my "content is not ascii" now you are saying that my "content might have non ascii stuff", what actually you are implying?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to state if the content is not ascii text the browser might try to download it as it cannot render it. I have retagged the query with javascript and browser tags. Can you mention whether this is across browser or specific to one brower?

Comment: Thanks for re-tagging the query. And yes, its across browser...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First remove the 'Content-Disposition' in your servlet.

Second, use a GWT `Anchor` in your code and when the user clicks open the link in a new window or an iframe.

Here you have a example using new window, and another using iframe:

```
    final String url = "http://gwtquery.googlecode.com/git/README.txt";
    String name = "README.txt";

    Anchor link1 = new Anchor(name);
    RootPanel.get().add(link1);
    link1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.open(url, "_blank", "");
      }
    });

    Anchor link2 = new Anchor(name);
    RootPanel.get().add(link2);
    link2.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Frame f = new Frame(url);
        f.setSize("600px", "400px");
        f.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(0, Unit.PX);
        RootPanel.get().add(f);
      }
    });
```

This approach works for any file which the browser is capable to display, but be sure that you send the appropriate `Content-Type` header (text/plain, text/html, image/png etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Will be back after checking this out.

Comment: Manolo: I got the same problem still, when I click on the link the browser again show a dialogue box to download it.
As you said i changed my 'response.setHeader("","")' to  'resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");'.

Comment: I had attached, what I implemented based on your query, as an UPDATE in my original query, please check through that also.

Comment: if you change the url by the one i sent in my example, does it work?, does it happen with any browser? could you take a look to the browser-server dialog? use firebug for that and attach the headers info.

Comment: I didn't try it the url you provided. But, as you said i tried like by changing "resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.txt");"  to "resp.setHeader("Content-Type:", "text/html; charset=utf-8");", then works fine, expect for the format of the content in my uploaded file.

Comment: I dont follow, so it's continuing asking you to save the file instead of showing its content in the iframe?

Comment: No no, when I change setHeader parameter to as above, it stopped showing save dialogue box. Only one single problem if there is two line in uploaded, the frame show one single line (it misses '\n').

Comment: It seems you are not sending Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: In my working code I was trying to send a text file, and I actually need PDF type file, means content type is "application/pdf", anyway I am missing '\n', and when its pdf missing all content.

Comment: Be aware that certain browsers can not display pdf files, so they will ask to the user to save the file. If you are in a browser which supports pdf and the file is not displayed, maybe you are sending a corrupted file from your server. If you write the url of your pdf file in the address bar you can test if the pdf can be displayed in your browser and if it is not corrupted.

Comment: I was trying in Chrome and Firefox. In both an UI for showing pdf is visible when I request for file from server. So, as you say, I am also feels like its due to corruption in the file itself from server side. If so I am thinking to add on more query related to that, what do you think?

Comment: You have to isolate the problem, if writing the url of the file in the address-bar it asks for saving the file: it is a server issue (check headers, try saving it and to open with a pdf reader, etc). If you visit an url (in Internet, not at your server) with a pdf and your browser displays correctly the content, use this link in your UI to assure that the ui is working. And based on your isolated problem open a specific question in stackoverflow. The query you asked here is answered and few people will look into this.